# jQuery document handlers stealing key presses in input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has probably been asked before, but I am not able to find a suitable search phrase to locate it, either here or on the intertubes.

I have a web page for a game which uses the keyboard, so with jQuery I have set handlers in the document:

```
$(document).keydown(myKeydown);
$(document).keyup(myKeyup);
$(document).blur(myBlur);
```

But now any text written in an input field is stolen by the document event handlers, and characters only reach the input if they are not used in the document handlers. These handlers in essence look like this:

```
function myKeydown(event)
{
    if (event.which == 65)
    {
        console.log('a pressed');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now imagine that I have a text input box; if I press any key other than 'a' it shows in the input, but not 'a' (since myKeydown is "eating" it by returning false). I could return true in any case, but then if no input box is focused I get weird things like "search when you type", if enabled.

I have tried to add handlers for the input box:

```
input.keydown(function() { console.log('down'); return false; });
input.keyup(function() { console.log('up'); return false; });
input.blur(function() { console.log('blur'); return false; });
```

With this code I get the console.logs, but of course keys don't reach the box (because I am doing nothing with the presses). Can I send these events somewhere so the corresponding keys appear in the input box?

**Note:** some people have suggested to use `event.stopPropagation()` instead of `return false`. [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) say:

> Returning false from a handler is equivalent to calling both .preventDefault() and .stopPropagation() on the event object."

That is precisely what I want: to prevent "search as you type" from kicking in, I have to prevent the default action, which is to type on an input and to "search as you type" on the page.

(Also, for some reason the `keydown` event handler does not have a stopPropagation() function on Firefox latest.)

Comment: As adeneo said, for the input handlers, you want to use `e.stopPropagation();`, not `return false;` (where `e` is the `event` being passed in)

Comment: @Ian Not a good idea: if I don't return false then "search for text when I start typing" kicks in and I get a search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to prevent this.

1. get the target in the event handler and ignore your code if the target is an `input`/`textarea`
2. bind the same event to the inputs and stop propagation

the first option is the right thing to do, IMO. Try:

```
if ($(event.target).is('input, textarea, select'))
{
    return true;
}
```

at the start of the event handler.

Comment: Could this be done using `on`, e.g. `$(document).on("keydown", ":not(input,textarea)", myKeydown);`?

Comment: @Barmar I think so! I wouldn't recommend this for mouse events like mousemove because of the processing it takes to evaluate the target based on the (possibly complex) selector, after it parses the selector. I'm not sure how well it would fare for fast typers, but still

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the specific code in jQuery, but I suspect it's basically the same as calling `.is()` -- they both have to parse the selector and then check the event target against it.

Comment: as an aside, I personally always use .on anway - if you decide to add or remove the limiting selector it's less of a syntactic change, and all your code follows the same pattern. Also, I typically only bind events to a parent container with a selector anyway, as there's less start-up code and the only browser that struggles with the propagation is IE6, so meh...

Answer (score 2):

To make comment of adeneo clean:

```
function myKeydown(event)
{
    if (event.which == 65)
    {
        console.log('a pressed');
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
$(document).keydown(myKeydown);
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VfTHB/)

Comment: Note that I said that I did want to prevent "search as you type" to kick in. Changing to your code does not prevent it.

Comment: you want to prevent console log, when you type in input ? this refers to prevent bubling

Comment: No, I want to prevent "search for text when I start typing", which is the default action. `return false` also prevents bubbling so there is no improvement in that area. Please see the note I added to the question.